# image path to textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working at a project and i want to save the path of the image saved in Content/assets folder in database .curenttly i am saving the path by passing it in a textbox and then transmit to my create method.How can i make a photo picker and save the path to my textbox?
Here is my view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Rooms", FormMethod.Get, new { @encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
  <div class="editor-label">    
  @Html.Label("RoomNumber")
  @Html.TextBox("RoomNumber")
  </div>
  <div class="editor-label">
   @Html.Label("RoomType")
   @Html.DropDownList("RoomType_id", new SelectList(Model.tip.AsEnumerable(), "RoomType_ID", "Room_Type"))
   </div>
   @Html.Label("Floor")
   @Html.DropDownList("Floor_id", new SelectList(Model.etaj.AsEnumerable(), "Floor_ID", "Denumire"))
   <div class="editor-label">
   @Html.Label("NumberOfSpots")
   @Html.TextBox("NumberOfSpots")
   </div>
   <div class="editor-label">
   @Html.Label("Status")
   @Html.TextBox("Status")                   
   </div>
   <div class="editor-label">
   @Html.Label("Status")
   @Html.TextBox("Status")                   
   </div>
   <div class="editor-label">
   @Html.Label("AlbumArtUrl")
   @Html.TextBox("AlbumArtUrl")                  
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `input type="file"`?

```
<input id="photo" type="file" />
```

Then you can hook into the change event in jQuery if needs be, like so:

```
$("#photo").change(function () {
    //do your stuff
});
```